# Should I unbind on Dispose?

Tags: c#, .net

If I bind stuff to a `Control` by calling the `Add` method of its `DataBindings` property, will the control's `Dispose` method remove the bindings automatically or do I have to remove them manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't have to.